# Langchain Recursive URL Loader scraping different amount of pages for the same URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, langchain, langchain-js

I am using Langchain Recursive URL Loader and I am testing it on the Next.js Documentation it should scrape the same amount of pages consistently but when I run it the number of pages scrapped is always different

```
import { RecursiveUrlLoader } from 'langchain/document_loaders/web/recursive_url';
import { compile } from 'html-to-text';

export const handleScrape = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, url } = req.body; // extract title and url from the request body

  const compiledConvert = compile({ wordwrap: 130 }); // returns (text: string) => string;

  // if (!url) {
  //   res.status(400).send('No url provided');
  //   return;
  // }

  const loader = new RecursiveUrlLoader(url, {
    extractor: compiledConvert,
    maxDepth: 50, // adjust as needed
  });

  const docs = await loader.load();
  console.log(`Scraped ${docs.length} documents from ${title}`);

  res.send(docs);
};
```

[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynjHw.png)

I expected the same amount of Links scraped since it is the same website